# How do I set a favorite place in Plesk 11?

Tags: plesk

I often want to load phpMyAdmin but it takes about 5 clicks to the WebAdmin icon in Plesk 11. Pervious versions of Plesk had favorites so I could get there in one click from the main page. I tried to bookmark the page in my browser, but that results in an error if I log out and back in. Does Plesk 11 offer favorites?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no "Favourites" in Plesk 11, but there are "Custom buttons".
You can create custom button on admin's home page with link to `"/server/db_servers.php?cmd=dbwebadmin&db_server_id=1"`

This URL may be different for your server, you can take it on "Database servers" page.